# how to give the condition in for loop?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

how to give condition in for loop. I want to do

```
for i in range(1,i <= n,1): 
for j in range(1,j <= i,1):
```

Those above statements are not working why i do not know. I am newbie to python. please give the suggestion.

```
class trianglePro:
    n = int(input("Enter number : "))
    i = 1
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,n,1):
        for j in range(1,i,1):
            print (" j: ", j)
        print("")
```

now output is:
  Enter number : 5

```
 j:  1

 j:  1
 j:  2

 j:  1
 j:  2
 j:  3
```

wanted output is:

```
Enter the value for n:5
  1 
  1 2 
  1 2 3 
  1 2 3 4 
  1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Do you previously used C/C++/Java/...?

Comment: As described in [First steps toward programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=indentation#first-steps-towards-programming), proper indentation is important in python.  The [Python documentation for **range**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) has examples which should help you with your loops.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem i used java previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do :

```
from __future__ import print_function

n = int(input("Enter number : "))
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(1,i+2):
    print (j,end=' ')
  print('')
```

Ouput :

```
Enter number : 5
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Drop the first line if you use python 3

Answer (score 0):

## Range statement

Python uses a `for` loop with syntax:

```
for <pattern> in <iterable-expression>:
    # ...
```

So the `for` loop in Python is what a `foreach` loop is in the C/C++/Java/C# family (in Java it is usually `for(Var var : iterable)`).

The `range(..)` is a constructor that is an iterable. If you construct a `range(0,5,2)` object, it will emit `0`, `2`, and `4`. There is no dedicated syntax like <s>`for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`</s> in Python.

## Print without new lines

A `print` statement automatically adds a *new line* at the end. So if you write `print(4)`, you write `"4\n"` to the output channel. You can however override the `end` parameter of `print` to prevent this: you can write `print(4, end='')` to only write `"4"` to the standard output channel. So you can rewrite your code to:

```
n = int(input("Enter number : "))
for i in range(1,n+1,1):
    for j in range(1,i+1,1):
        print (j, end=' ')
    print('')
```

Note that you also should drop the `" j: "` in the print statement, since otherwise it will print that to the output channel as well. For example:

```
>>> n=5
>>> for i in range(1,n+1,1):
...     for j in range(1,i+1,1):
...         print (j, end=' ')
...     print('')
... 
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

In [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), you better import the `print(..)` function from [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) by writing:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

in the head of the file.

Comment: This does not do what he wants, the output is not the correct one.

Comment: @williem Thank you very much for your theory and program.